# How do I show a Snap.js menu only on mobiles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I made a website with a Bootstrap navbar, but on mobiles, I want to show my Snap.js shelf instead. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: I tried nothing, because I had really no idea how to do it and I didn't know of hidden-xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `.hidden-xx` class.

You can do the following to hide the Bootstrap navbar on a phone and show the Snap.js shelf instead:

```
// Snap.js
// Visible only on xs screen sizes
<div class="snap-drawers hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
    ...
</div>

// Bootstrap
// Hidden on xs screen sizes
<nav class="navbar hidden-xs">
    ...
</nav>
```